# Visiting Netherlands with Italian Schengen visa without visiting Italy

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy, netherlands, itineraries

I had a plan to visit Italy on a company trip. Got the visa from the Italian embassy but unfortunately, the company has now changed plans to visit the Netherlands. The company says I can travel to the Netherlands with this visa but won't be visiting Italy at all. But my visa also mentions that I need to report back to the embassy after travel. I am confused as in what to do as I don't have time to apply for the Netherlands visa also. Will this have any issue for my next visas?

Answer (score 1):

- This "report back" thing indicates that they considered you a high risk of overstay, but not quite risky enough to deny a visa. The key thing is that you show up in the Italian embassy in your homeland to prove that you are no longer in Italy (or anywhere else in Schengen).
- You could travel to Italy via the Netherlands and get exactly the same stamps in your passport as for a visit to the Netherlands only.
- However, it would be a breach of the rules. You **should** have the current visa cancelled and apply for a new one. This will cost money and take time you may not have, but your company is gambling with **your** visa history. A black mark could last for a long time.